# Formula 45-RowCount

Tags: formula

I'm trying to use simple formula: *45-RowCount* and it is working fine if RowCount is >0. If =0 it returns no value, and I want it to return 45 if RowCount=0. What should be done differently here?

Comment: Could you post your formula?

Comment: this is exactly: 45-RowCount

Comment: What is `RowCount` in your formula? What is it referring to?

Comment: it is referring to list of activities with event type=other.

Answer (score 0):

Numerical formulas can specify a desired behavior if a referenced field is null: you can either treat the field as null, in which case your own formula will return null, or you can treat it as a zero.

Your formula appears to be treating null as null and returning an empty result. Change the setting for handling blank fields to treat them as zero.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information from OP on this question and the formula being used, it appears from the comments that `RowCount` has a list of activities, likely be a number, and with that your formula would be

`45 - IF ( IsBlank(RowCount),  0, RowCount )`

P.S. I am also not aware as to why `45` is being referenced here. Please do mention these little details which would help us , help you better and even suggest a different approach to solve your problem.

Comment: 45 referrs to total working days in a week in 9-person team. All-day Events with type=other are referring to days of absence. in result I want to get effective selling days in a specific week.

Comment: Now that's more like it. You should include this information in your original post. However, the answer remains the same.